# Is there an established name for this anti-pattern?

Tags: anti-patterns

Quite often I see code that use redundant properties for data, when one value could have been calculated on the fly from two others. To me it is an obvious anti-pattern, as it makes further work on the code much harder. Every time you change one value you are expected to know how it relates to other values and change those too. If you mess this up, there is an ambiguous situation where you don't know what values are correct and what aren't.

However, I don't know if this is a "known" anti-pattern with an established name.

```rb
# Bad
class Rectangle
  attr_accessor: height
  attr_accessor: width
  attr_accessor: ratio

  def initialize
    @height = 1
    @width = 1
    @ratio = 1
  end
end

# Good
class Rectangle
  attr_accessor: height
  attr_accessor: width

  def initialize
    @height = 1
    @width = 1
  end

  def ratio
   @width.to_f / @height
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't always bad.  Some things are expensive to calculate, and you often need to cache dependent values. And often the dependency between values can be fluid.

Comment: True, forgot to write that. Caching values is allowed, but then it should be obvious which value is cached and what values it derives from.

Comment: ...and you should have mechanisms in place to update outdated cached values. (Fine, store `ratio`, but remember which values you derived it from, and check if those values have changed in the meantime.)

Comment: @DevSolar Typically edits are rare, and you can just update the cache when one of the values it's dependent on is updated. But this doesn't address dependency fluidity anyway.  So you also sometimes need to keep track of which values are considered "independent" and which ones are considered "cached", and it changes depending on what the user sets.

Comment: @Spencer: I don't quite get what you're saying. On the one hand edits are rare, but on the other hand what a value actually depends on is in flux, i.e. an X is sometimes an A/B and sometimes an A*C? Sounds like broken to me... (Anyway, I guess we're getting distracted here...)

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, it happens; but yeah, this is a tangent...

Comment: I'd argue that in cases where computing the derived data is complex it is often better to return it precomputed, especially where the caller is (in some sense) a 'client' of whatever 'service' returned the data.  For example, I'm currently working on some code that returns a blob of marked up text with embedded links of various kinds *plus* an attached list of those links (id, path, label, type).  The client could parse the links out themselves, but why make them?  A similar argument can be made when returning tabular data with derived columns.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a violation of [don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

> Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system.

---

> Violations of DRY are typically referred to as WET solutions, which is commonly taken to stand for "write every time", "write everything twice", "we enjoy typing" or "waste everyone's time".

Comment: I've only seen that phrase used for the code itself, not data-structures, but it makes sense to me!

Comment: @Eneroth3: The principle is the same. In a database, this would be violating [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).